# IntelliJ IDEA11 can't detect compilation error in Play project

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

Take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: If you navigate to Model declaration (Ctrl+B), which class will it be? play.db.jpa.Model or something else?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but do you have a class called Model in your Models package?

Comment: Yes, the package name of Model is play.db.jpa in play.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the Community or the Ultimate version ?

The play! module is not available in the Community version.

Comment: Strange. I have no problem with my Intellij 11 and Play! projects. You installed version 11 from scratch or it was an upgraded of version 10 ? Maybe try a fresh install.

Comment: It turn out to be ok when I restart IntelliJ